# Drawing a ellipse using parametric equations in Java

Tags: java, arrays, shapes

I am trying code below but it is not working as expected, please help.

```
for(int i =0;i<20;i++){
    double angle = i * 2 * Math.PI/20; 
    int rdif = (int) Math.round(yradius * Math.cos(angle));
    int row = ycenter + rdif;
    int cdif = (int) Math.round(xradius * Math.sin(angle));
    int col = xcenter + cdif;
    index[row][col] = '*';
}
```

xcenter is 10, 
ycenter is 10,
xradius is 5,
yradius is 3

Check the image for output:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIVZz.png)

Comment: Can you explain what this program is expected to do?  The image you posted looks like an ellipse to me...

Comment: I just want to draw an eclipse with centre coordinates, x-radius and y-radius. You can see image formed is not a like perfect eclipse.. You can see another image where x-radius is 3 and y-radius is 2.

Comment: I hate to give you such a bad answer, but I think that's the best you're going to get drawing it in text.  Right now you have it set to draw 20 `*`s, you can adjust that hardcoded number to make it look better at different sizes, or you could even make that number change dynamically with the size of the ellipse.  I honestly don't think your screenshots look that bad, though.